# Testing Spring JAX-WS Web Services

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-ws

I have a Web Service (`@WebService`) exported with `SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter`.

I want to create integration tests for it.

How can I do this? Is possible to use the `MockWebServiceClient` class from the `spring-ws-test` project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the `MockWebServiceClient` works with Spring-WS services only.

Answer (score 0):

You either can create client-side or server-side test cases.

I prefer server side test as you do not have to delploy your application at all. It should be an out-of-container test.

> SEREVR SIDE Spring-WS Test (NO DEPLOYMENT REQUIRED) - Keep in mind the following points.

```
import org.springframework.ws.test.server.MockWebServiceClient

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = YOUR CONTEXT XML FILE LOCATION


/**
        *  <strong>Main entry point for server-side Web service testing</strong>. Typically used to test a {@link
        *  org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher MessageDispatcher} (including its endpoints, mappings, etc) by
        *  creating request messages, and setting up expectations about response messages.
        */
        private MockWebServiceClient mockServiceClient;

        @Before
         public void setUp() throws Exception{
             mockServiceClient = MockWebServiceClient.createClient(applicationContext);
         }

        @Test

 mockServiceClient.sendRequest(withPayload(VALID_PAYLOAD_REQUEST)).andExpect(VALID_PAYLOAD_RES)
```

> CLIENT SIDE Spring-WS TEST - YOU HAVE TO DEPLOY EAR or WAR

```
public class CountryServiceClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport

String uri = "http://localhost:8080/Endpointaddress/url

request = User.class/ anythig else/ make the bean ready

Object response = getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(uri, request, new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
            //real call to webservice make sure your application is up and running with the above uri.
            @Override
            public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException, TransformerException {

                   SaajSoapMessage soapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) message;
                   MimeHeaders mimeHeader = soapMessage.getSaajMessage().getMimeHeaders();
                   mimeHeader.setHeader("ApplicationId", "Z1012922");
                   mimeHeader.setHeader("userid", "aacom");
            }
        });
```